# Cannot convert unsigned int to unsigned int & (Boost adjacency iterator pointer)

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, types, iterator

I have a graph in Boost Graph Library and a template function `heapV`. I declared the template class as `heapV <Graph::vertex_descriptor , Graph> lookAt;` so typename T should be a `vertex_descriptor`.

There's a function `int heapV<T,U>::getIndex(T &key)` that I want to call. I'm trying `myHeapV.getIndex(*vItr)`, but get the error

> cannot convert from unsigned int to unsigned int&.

`vItr` is an adjacency iterator from BGL, and an adjacency iterator pointer returns an unsigned int.

I'll provide more details if anyone needs.

Answer (score 1):

getIndex requires an lvalue parameter.

So you should probably (who knows, I don't know that the `getIndex` function does), use a (temporary) variable:

```
unsigned int key = *vItr;
int index = myHeapV.getIndex(key); // lvalue reference
```

> If the code compiled on MSVC, that's because of non-standard compiler extensions it uses